# Objective Sharpie with no header files

Tags: objective-c, xamarin, objective-sharpie

I am trying to use Objective Sharpie with a third party library fir which I only have the `.a` file. From my understanding, I need the header files to do the binding. Is there a way that I can make Objective Sharpie work with this or a way to generate the header files?

Comment: just use lipo command to generate .a and create objective sharpie command